# isvalid rss feed url

Tags: xml, rss

Before adding a rss feed url to the database, how can i check and make sure that it a valid rss url.

via vb.net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find whether a URL is a valid RSS URL is to go there and check what you get. Use a WebRequest to fetch the URL, and see if what you get back is a valid RSS file (i.e. is it XML? if so, does it have the elements you expect it to have? (namely posts))

Comment: Thanks Yuliy. I am able to check the required elements.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

[Validate a URL in Visual Basic .NET](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_validate_url.html)